# Sorting lists based on first integer

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I got a problem regarding sorting a list within Python. For some reason it does rank the list on the highest value but after that process is done, other elements within that list are not sorted anymore.

My code:

```
import csv

id_list = []

with open('source/to/file/output.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        test = "177"
        if test == row[0]:
            id_list.append([row[2],row[1]])            

generated_list = id_list[0], id_list[16], id_list[20]

print(generated_list)
print(sorted(generated_list))
```

The result of the print is:

```
-- (['17', '179'], ['5', '2641'], ['9', '3705']) # not sorted
-- [['17', '179'], ['5', '2641'], ['9', '3705']] # sorted
```

What I would expect is that the sorting method will output:

```
-- [['17', '179'], ['9', '3705'], ['5', '2641']] # sorted
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect that? Python is **strongly typed**, it won't treat strings as numbers. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/3001761 for some alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python sort your lists based on first element lexicographicaly because you have string, for get ride of that use a key function to sort based on `int` value :

```
print(sorted(generated_list,key=lambda x:int(x[0]),reverse=True))
```

Demo :

```
>>> sorted(generated_list,key=lambda x:int(x[0]),reverse=True)
[['17', '179'], ['9', '3705'], ['5', '2641']]
```

Or as says in comment you can convert your number to integer before sorting,also you can unpack your rows for refuse multiple indexing :

```
with open('source/to/file/output.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        test = "177"
        row1,row2,row3=row
        if test == row1:
            id_list.append([int(row2),row(row1)])
```

Comment: Oh that is awesome! Thank you so much! That did the trick! As soon as I can mark you answer I will do it!

Comment: Assuming that OP wants to work with that data, it might be better to permanently convert the values to `int`, though.

Comment: @tobias_k Yep, that would be better!